# iterate array without recursion

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm searching and trying for days... sorry!
i have an array like the one below. It is ordered but i may not know how deep it goes. I need to walk through it, every child nodes. I don't want to use recursion, as i need to integrate this into another block of code and it would difficult myself. I'm looking for something simple like a foreach, but this will only give me the 3 parent nodes... i need to have each node in one "block" as i will need to access them like `$arr['id_categoria']` and `$arr['nome_categoria']`, etc

any suggestion?
thanks a lot!

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_categoria] => 3
            [nome_categoria] => Bebidas
            [id_categoria_pai] => 0
            [submenu] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id_categoria] => 5
                            [nome_categoria] => Alcoolicas
                            [id_categoria_pai] => 3
                            [submenu] => Array
                                (
                                    [10] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_categoria] => 10
                                            [nome_categoria] => Espirituosas
                                            [id_categoria_pai] => 5
                                            [submenu] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [id_categoria] => 11
                            [nome_categoria] => sem alcool
                            [id_categoria_pai] => 3
                            [submenu] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_categoria] => 4
            [nome_categoria] => Sandes
            [id_categoria_pai] => 0
            [submenu] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id_categoria] => 7
            [nome_categoria] => Outros pedidos
            [id_categoria_pai] => 0
            [submenu] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: If you don't know the depth you need recursion!

Comment: @JackManey How do you determine the maximum depth without recursion?

Comment: First: this should of course be done *with* recursion. Second: `array_walk_recursive` can probably do most of the work for you. And last: StackOverlow is a place to ask and to learn -- not to say how you 'd like your steak and wait for someone else to cook it.

Comment: @leftclickben - I didn't scroll down enough on the OP's `var_dump()` output to realize that the array has an actual branching tree structure. If it weren't for branches, then you could go through a `while` loop, `break`ing if a given value has no integer key. But yeah...with the array as it is above, OP will need recursion.

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions! @Jon: i didn't ask for a steak, i told what i needed and then i asked for suggestions on how to get there. it's different!

Answer (score 1):

For this, you HAVE TO use recursion, since you do not know how deep it goes.

But, you can make a recursive function to extract all single values in an array.

Comment: Actually it's possible to do it without recursion, as is everything else. You simply take the recursive algorithm and transform it to its iterative version. But it's a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion? You don't need no (explicit) recursion! Just use a [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php), wrap it in a [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), and iterate, like this:

```
$array = array(); // From the OP

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator( $array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST); 

foreach( $iter as $el) {
    echo $el['id_categoria'];
}
```

For your array, this will print:

```
3 
5
10 
11 
etc.
```

Done!